Why are the yticks on one of the plots getting compressed?
I have written a script to conduct innovative trend analysis.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from scipy import stats
mpl.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'

for i, station in enumerate(stations):
    df = pd.read_excel(r"D:\rainfall data\DATA_NEW\Rainfall_Data_All_Stations_Time_Series.xlsx", sheet_name=station, index_col='Year')
    mid = len(df) // 2
    df1 = df.iloc[:mid]
    df2 = df.iloc[mid:]
    cols = df.columns
    
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 6, figsize=(15, 7))
    
    for j, col in enumerate(cols):
        k = j // 6
        l = j % 6
        ax = axs[k, l]
        x = np.sort(df1[col])
        y = np.sort(df2[col])
        
        ax.scatter(x, y)
        
        
        # Calculate confidence interval
        slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(x, y)
        y_mean = slope * x + intercept
        confidence = 1.96 * np.sqrt(np.mean((y - y_mean)**2))
        
        # Plot 1:1 line
        ax.plot([np.min(x), np.max(x)], [np.min(y), np.max(y)], color='red', linestyle='--')
        
        # Plot upper and lower bounds of confidence interval
        ax.fill_between([min(x), max(x)], [min(y) + confidence, max(y) + confidence], 
                        [min(y) - confidence, max(y) - confidence], color='blue', alpha=0.2)

        x_min, x_max = np.floor(x.min()), np.ceil(x.max())
        y_min, y_max = np.floor(y.min()), np.ceil(y.max())
        x_tick_positions = np.linspace(x_min, x_max, 4)
        y_tick_positions = np.linspace(y_min, y_max, 5)
        
        x_tick_positions = np.round(x_tick_positions).astype(int)
        y_tick_positions = np.round(y_tick_positions).astype(int)
        
        ax.set_xticks(x_tick_positions)
        ax.set_yticks(y_tick_positions)
        
        #ax.set_xlim([min(x_tick_positions), max(x_tick_positions)])
        #ax.set_ylim([min(y_tick_positions), max(y_tick_positions)+1])
        
        ax.set_title(col, fontweight='bold')
        
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()     
    break

This results in the following: 
As you may notice, in case of the plot for April, the yticks are compressed unlike any other subplot. I have found the cause for this being the part of the script which plots the confidence interval (shaded region) and when I remove that part,it results in the following 

Is there a reason you replace the default ticks with these strange irregular onces? Maybe you could just set ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(4)) (exact multiple of 4)? Or MaxNLocator(nbins=6, integer=True) (maximum 6 ticks on "regular" positions, forced to be integers)?
